# PCRE regex behaves differently when moved to subroutine

Tags: regex, pcre, pcregrep

Using PCRE v8.42, I am trying to abstract a regex into a named subroutine, but when it's in a subroutine, it seems to behave differently.

This outputs `10/`:

```
echo '10/' | pcregrep '(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/'
```

This outputs nothing:

```
echo '10/' | pcregrep '(?(DEFINE)(?<MONTHNUM>(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])))(?&MONTHNUM)\/'
```

Are these two regular expressions not equivalent?

Comment: Right, you need `(?<MONTHNUM>(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In versions of PCRE2 [prior to 10.30](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html), all subroutine calls are [always treated](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) as [atomic groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html). Your `(?(DEFINE)(?<MONTHNUM>(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])))(?&MONTHNUM)\/` regex is actually equal to `(?>0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIFY6p/3), where `10/` does not match as expected.

There is no match because `0?[1-9]` matched the `1` in `10/` and since there is no backtracking allowed, the second alternative was not tested ("entered"), and the whole match failed as there is no `/` after `1`.

You need to make sure the longer alternative comes first:

```php
(?(DEFINE)(?<MONTHNUM>(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])))(?&MONTHNUM)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIFY6p/2). Note that in the `pcregrep` pattern, you do not need to escape `/`.

Alternatively, you can use PCRE2 v10.30 or newer.